# Doesn't show image

Tags: javascript

I am expecting the code to show the picture randomly.

Trying to put a random image in my HTML via the JavaScript DOM but it isn't  showing in the browser.  I am getting an error `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Image (async) (anonymous)` @ app.js:14

The console is telling that the problem is at `diceDOM.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';`

Here is code:

```js
var scores, roundScore, activePlayer;
scores       = [0,0];
roundScore   = 0;                                               
activePlayer = 1;

document.querySelector('.dice').style.display = 'none';

document.querySelector('.btn-roll').addEventListener('click', function(){
  //1. Random Number
  var dice = Math.floor(Math.random () * 6) + 1;
  //2. Display the Results
  var diceDOM = document.querySelector('.dice');
  diceDOM.style.display = 'block';
  diceDOM.src = 'dice-' + dice + '.png';
});
```

Comment: `net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND Image` would suggest that the image is not there. Are you sure the path is correct to dice-*-.png?

Comment: Definitely, or maybe do you have any alternative way i can use to select the image?

Comment: If your image is at the root of your site, you could always try to path it absolutely to `/dice-*.png` with a `/`.

Comment: Okay let me try that...